# Unittest Python - Why Create a Class?

Tags: python, testing

Suppose you are writing unit tests with the unittest framework within Python.

I am used to writing unit tests using classes and various methods for each test e.g. if you had some function `cuboid_volume` that calculates the volume of a cube:

```
def cuboid_volume(l):
    return (l*l*l)
```

Then you would structure units tests as follows:

```
import unittest

class TestCuboid(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_volume(self):
      self.assertAlmostEqual(cuboid_volume(2),8)
```

However I have also seen examples where unit tests are structured without using a class. Example below:

```
def test_volume():
  assert cuboid_volume(2) == 8
```

My question is: what is the benefit of doing this and why use a class in the first place?

Comment: If there is a `self`, it has got to be part of some class.

Comment: Because that's what unittest is designed to do, in common with other "xUnit" test frameworks. There are, as you say, other ways of structuring tests (although some, like the "xSpec" pattern, don't really work in Python as the language doesn't have anonymous functions with more than a single expression).

Comment: I removed the self in the second function... that shouldn't have been there

Comment: As @jonrsharpe says, `unittest` mimics idioms from test frameworks in other languages. I don't like having to write a class either, that's why I prefer `pytest`.

Comment: classes give structure, you can properly and easily group tests for the same method, you can share some initialization of context objects, etc.

Comment: Being in a subclass of unittest.TestCase gives you access to a bunch of `self.assert...` methods. But pytest has more succinct approach.

Answer (score 2):

benefit to use class

1. you can call inheritted method from class `unittest.TestCase`, that is why you can use `self.assertAlmostEqual`
2. group relevant test cases in a class so that they can share common data/properties among relevant test cases. also have same `setUp` and `tearDown` called per test method, or `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` per class.